# terraform aws ec2 instance ip address assignment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a typical problem with terraform and aws. I have to deploy 26 instances via terraform but they all should have ip address in an increment order.

for example

```
instance 1: 0.0.0.1
instance 2: 0.0.0.2
instance 3: 0.0.0.3
```

Is it possible somehow to achieve in terraform?

Comment: @MarkB You absolutely can select the private IP address of an instance or an ENI. But the other parts of your comment are useful and the point about subnets/availability zones is particularly important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, you can find an **example** of how to do it. It just creates for instances with ip range from `172.31.64.100` to `172.31.64.104` (you can't use first few numbers as they are reserved by AWS).

You will have to **adjust subnet id and initial IP range** which I used in my example to your subnets. You also must **ensure** that these IP addresses are not used. AWS could already use them for its load balances in your VPC, existing instances or other services. If any IP address in this range is already taken, it will fail.

```
locals {
  ip_range = [for val in range(100, 104): "172.31.64.${val}"]
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "foo" {

  for_each    = toset(local.ip_range)

  subnet_id   = "subnet-b64b8988"
  
  private_ips = [each.key]

  tags = {
    Name = "primary_network_interface"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {

  for_each      = toset(local.ip_range)

  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  
  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.foo[each.key].id
    device_index         = 0
  }  

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```